# Advanced conditions in Database Abstraction Layer?

Tags: database

I have a module with a custom schema in it. On my cron job, I want to delete records older than 90 days. There is a date field in the table that holds a unix timestamp.

The query I want to run is `DELETE FROM table WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - date > 778000`, where 7780000 is the number of seconds in 90 days.

To test my query, I tried to make a select query with the same conditions:

```
$results = db_select('table')
->fields('table', array('field'))
->condition('UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - date', 7780000, '>')
->execute()->fetchAssoc();
```

However, the database AL doesn't parse the conditional the way I want it to:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'UNIX_TIMESTAMPdate' in 'where clause': SELECT ...
```

How do I write this conditional properly in the database AL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the 'where' method for complex conditionals:

```
db_delete('table')
  ->where('UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - date > :date', array(':date' => 7780000))
  ->execute();
```